# Java 11 command line modules and Maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, java-11

It looks like I have to add all the JavaFX modules in the javac call as parameters to the `--add-modules` as parameters as listed in the Maven pom.xml file? Such that

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
</dependency>
```

matches `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml`. Correct?

And what about all the other dependencies listed in the pom.xml like

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I have some more. Do I have to add these the `--add-modules` as well? If so, how?

Comment: `mvn package` should take care of this already

Comment: Is your application modular or not? I.e. do you have `module-info.java` in your modules?

Comment: no modules as of yet